# Problem installing HP Laserjet M1136 in Ubuntu 14.04.14LTS

Tags: printing, hp

I'm new to ubuntu and trying to install the HP printer. All setting seem to be fine and the printer shows 'ready to print', but I can't even get the test page to print. Status say 'rendering completed', but show as 'stopped' I've seen some answers that explain there may be a bug. I'm not a programmer so can't really sort this out myself.

Please help.

[image]

Comment: Install hplip from hp site.

Comment: Thanks this was helpful. The printer is working.  For future, here's a quick reference manual.
1. Ensure you have your hplip driver already downloaded and installed at hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/installtree.html#debian.  They give a good overview of how to identify the driver installation.
2. In Ubuntu Software Center search for HPLIP Toolbox. If not installed, download and install.
3. Attach printer and follow on-screen instructions.
You are good to print.